# SQL Joining between 2 table [multi column to single column]

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables

```
List
id_1  id_2 tym event
1     2    xx   1
1     3    yy   2
2     1    zz   3

Details
id  name
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

I want to get `id_1.name, id_2.name, tym, event`
Expected result

```
a  b  xx 1   
a  c  yy 2   
b  a  zz 3
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: It's written below. I want to get id_1.name, id_2.name, tym, event

Comment: Please describe the relation between the two tables and post the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `details` table twice

```
select d1.name, d2.name, l.tym, l.event 
from List l
left join Details d1 on l.id_1 = d1.id
left join Details d2 on l.id_2 = d2.id
```

- [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/854bf4/1)